Question on exp-inequality
Let $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ be two bounded and finite sequences in $\mathbb{R}^1$, satisfying the condition that for any $t\in\mathbb{R}^1$, $$\sum_{a_i \geq t} a_i \geq \sum_{b_j \geq t} b_j.$$
Is it true that $$\sum \exp(a_i) \geq \sum \exp(b_j)?$$

What are the summation limits in the second inequality?

Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

This is trivial -- see e.g. this book.
Specifically, this follows immediately from the identity
$$\exp x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dt\, e^t f_t(x)$$
for real $x$, where $f_t(x):=1(x\ge t)$.
